# Why is UIGraphicsImageRenderer not working properly in UNNotificationServiceExtension?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm using this code to render my custom view to `UIImage`:

```
extension UIView {
    func toImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size)
        return renderer.image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I take this image and save it as a file.

Then I create `UNNotificationAttachment` with this file.

If I do these steps when creating a local notification within the main app target, notification displays icon (my custom rendered view) properly.

But if I run that same code in Notification Service Extension target, there is no icon on notification.

Does anyone have idea what could go wrong there?

P.S. If I'm not using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` like this:

```
func toImage() -> UIImage {
    return UIImage(named: "Test")!
}
```

then it works normally, but I don't have a possibility to use dynamic icons in notifications. Any idea for alternative solution?

Comment: You cannot draw the hierarchy in an extension; there is no hierarchy. If your goal is to draw an image, just draw it. Or did you mean to ask for a snapshot view?

Comment: @matt yes, I wanted to make a snapshot of the view, but this what you said about not having a hierarchy in the extension unfortunately makes sense, it's a bummer I can't snapshot any view there.

Comment: Well, it's hard for me to think of anything you could do with a view hierarchy that you couldn't do just as well by actual drawing. You don't need an image view; you can just draw the image. You don't need a label; you can just draw the text. And so on. And real drawing is _way_ faster than `drawHierarchy`.

Comment: I understand it's possible to draw that same UI, but that would require me to reimplement this custom view and its hierarchy (subviews and auto layout) in a different way. Thanks for explaining why it's impossible to snapshot a view in an extension though.